# Suggest tag Maps

Tags: feature-request, tags

I noticed there is no tag yet for Maps. The forum does not allow me to use it, because it looks too much like map, which is a completely different thing:

[image]

For those who don't know: I am referring to the Salesforce package Maps, previously known as MapAnything.

Comment: It doesn't let you create the tag by adding it to a post? I'm a bit on the fence about what the best tag name would be. I would say `[salseforce-maps]` but there is a long history on this site of abuse of any tag that has `salseforce` in the name.

Comment: No. I was surprised as well. Recently I have created a tag (I can't remember which one) without problems. But when I tried to create maps, the forum told me that it looks too much like map and that I should request it in this meta forum.